# "(#100) param data must be an array" Facebook Offline Conversions API error

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, post

I am getting this error on hitting the `/events` endpoint (POST REQUEST) to upload event. The URL I am hitting is `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/<EVENT_ID>/events` with payload something like this:

`{'upload_tag': <TIMESTAMP>, 'data': [{'currency': 'USD', 'event_time': <TIMESTAMP>, 'value': 0.0, 'match_key': {'email': '<EMAIL_HASH>'}, 'custom_data': {'event_source': 'event'}}], 'access_token': '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'}`

But am getting the error that params must be an array which it already is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please link to the documentation for the endpoint you are using there.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions

Comment: _“with payload something like this”_ - that looks like the whole thing was JSON, which is not what this endpoint expects. `upload_tag`, `data` and `access_token` are normal POST parameters, and only the _value_ of `data` is supposed to be a JSON string.

Comment: all other parameters except `data` are normal POST parameters. There seems to be issue with the `data` param.

Comment: Then show us how you are actually making the request and sending the data, and not some vague “payload something like” stuff …

Comment: im using request module in python, request.post(url, params). The params contain the parameters mentioned above.

Comment: Then provide `data` as a JSON-encoded string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183305/discussion-between-saad-khan-and-misorude).

Answer (score 1):

The data parameter accepts only JSON string, convert the data to json.dumps(object) and do an HTTP post.

Answer (score 0):

your payload should really be like this

```
$data = array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'upload_tag' => date(DB_DATE),
        'data' => array(
            json_encode(
                array(
                    'match_keys' => array(
                        'email' => hash('sha256', strtolower(trim($email)))
                    ),
                    'event_name' => 'Survey Complete',
                    'event_time' => strtotime($time),
                    'currency' => 'USD',
                    'contents' => array(json_encode(array('id' => $id, 'quantity' => $quantity))),
                    'value' => $points / 100,
                    'item_number' => $complete_id
                )
            )
        )
    );
```